# How to Create a Post List With Numbers in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

i want to create list post with number in elementor like this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HraBE.png)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then read [ask] here. After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [mre] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just post a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.